# Google Adwords dynamic value is not showing the right value

Tags: magento2, google-api, order-success-page, order-totals

I'm using Magento 2.1.4 and configured google adwords data for my magento store like this :

[image: configuration]

the google adwords code generated successfully, but the problem is the price value at checkout success always shows 39.6, even though i already set it to dynamic and my total order is always more than 1 million

[image: not the right value]

i already  deleted cache, did setup:upgrade, and static content deploy after finish setting the configuration